# A closed loop on $\mathbb{R}^2-{0}$ with a winding number of 2 or greater must intersect on at least one point

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Given a closed loop $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2-0$ that has winding number that is not $-1,0,1$ (By winding number  I mean given an isomorphism between the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^2-0$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ the element to which the homotopy class of $f$ gets sent to) then there is a pair of points $a,b\in(0,1)$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$ or that the loop is not injective for the open interval. Is this true? How would one prove this?

Comment: did you mean to ask about injectivity on $(0,1)$ or $[0,1)$?  Your question is explicitly about the former but the answer you accepted is about the latter.  For the former: winding numbers $\in \big\{0, \pm 1, \pm 2\big\}$ are all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Jordan curve theorem, the curve bounds a region homeomorphic to the disk, so the inclusion of the boundary of this region (the image of the curve) into the region is isomorphic (in the sense that the appropriate square with homeomorphisms commutes) to the inclusion of the circle into the unit disk.

Now we can remove the origin from both of these regions and this statement still stands. Hence, the inclusion induces an isomorphism on $\pi_1$. However, we have that $S^1 \rightarrow \operatorname{Im}(f) \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^2 -0$ is a degree 2 map, which is impossible since both maps in the composition are isomorphisms.